# Modify an excel file's sensitivity label without xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Currently I am tasked with automating an Excel spreadsheet's formulas using Python, but I came across an issue where I have to add a custom sensitivity label to a file programmatically without the use of the `xlwings` package or the `Set-AIPFileLabel` module for PowerShell. VBA is not an option either, only Python or perhaps Python running code in another language without `xlwings`. Thank you!

I have tried the `win32com` package without `xlwings` to no avail.